# MediaFoundation HEVC H265 encoding

Tags: c++, winapi, video-encoding, ms-media-foundation, hevc

I'm able to successfully encode H264 video using MediaFoundation.

Now I want to export HEVC which is, according to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/h-265---hevc-video-encoder), is supported.

I am doing everything as described there but whenever I want to set input media type to the writer it ends up with an error:

#### No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content.

Here is a short code of what i do:

/* Set output media type */

```
IMFMediaType* pMediaTypeOut = nullptr;
MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeOut);
pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_HEVC);
MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480);
MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1);
pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH265VProfile_Main_420_8);
pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_LEVEL, eAVEncH265VLevel1);

// Add it to the sink writer
m_pWriter->AddStream(pMediaTypeOut, &m_streamIndex);
```

/* Set input media type */

```
IMFMediaType* pMediaTypeIn = nullptr;
MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeIn);
pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_NV12);
MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480);
MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1),
MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1),

// Here it ends up with an error
m_pWriter->SetInputMediaType(m_streamIndex, pMediaTypeIn, nullptr);
```

Does anyone know if the HEVC encoding is really supported or it is just a documentation.
And if it is really supported by Microsoft, then what am I doing wrong?

BTW: I am using latest version of Windows 10.
Error checking is omitted for code simplicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can check the existence of the h265 encoder first by [DXVA Checker](https://bluesky23.yukishigure.com/en/DXVAChecker.html) tool or programmatically use [MFEnumEx(MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_ENCODER, ...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mftenumex) to lookup.

If not found, you can try installing the [HEVC Video Extension on MS App Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/hevc-video-extensions/9nmzlz57r3t7?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab). It seems MS has separated the MF HEVC codec into app package after 2018 Fall Creator update. Also, the HW HEVC Encoder needed be installed via vendor's VGA driver.

Comment: Yeah! Installing the extension and the code from @Roman helped me! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Your output media type is incomplete:

> `MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE`
>   Average encoded bit rate, in bits per second. Must be greater than zero.

Similar problem with `MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE`.

Code snippet that works:

```cpp
Check(MFStartup(MF_VERSION));

ComPtr<IMFSinkWriter> SinkWriter;
Check(MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(L"D:\\temp.mp4", nullptr, nullptr, SinkWriter.GetAddressOf()));

ComPtr<IMFMediaType> OutputMediaType;
Check(MFCreateMediaType(OutputMediaType.GetAddressOf()));
Check(OutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));
Check(OutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_HEVC));
Check(MFSetAttributeSize(OutputMediaType.Get(), MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480));
Check(OutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive));
Check(MFSetAttributeRatio(OutputMediaType.Get(), MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1));
//Check(OutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH265VProfile_Main_420_8));
//Check(OutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_LEVEL, eAVEncH265VLevel1));
Check(OutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 1000000));

DWORD StreamIndex;
Check(SinkWriter->AddStream(OutputMediaType.Get(), &StreamIndex));

ComPtr<IMFMediaType> InputMediaType;
Check(MFCreateMediaType(InputMediaType.GetAddressOf()));
Check(InputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));
Check(InputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_NV12));
Check(MFSetAttributeSize(InputMediaType.Get(), MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480));
Check(InputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive));
Check(MFSetAttributeRatio(InputMediaType.Get(), MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1)),
//Check(MFSetAttributeRatio(InputMediaType.Get(), MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1)),

Check(SinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(StreamIndex, InputMediaType.Get(), nullptr));
```